# How to say "moving in to a new house"

Tags: лексикон

I was wondering how you can say in Russian that you are moving into a new house/apartment or moving to a new city (to live there, not to visit it). I find it difficult to find a good translation for this, since in most contexts "to move" means something else. Moreover, without asking a native speaker it's hard to check whether a word has the right connotation or not (for example, "to migrate" would have a similar meaning but different connotation to "to move"). Could someone help me translate this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in addition to переехать, a very official term is поменять место жительства (used in official documents).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verb is переехать

> Переехать в новый дом, в новую квартиру, переехать в другой город.

The verb is perfective. Its imperfective pair is переезжать.

> За свою жизнь они несколько раз переезжали с квартиры на квартиру, с места на место.

Answer (score 1):

I would respectfully disagree with the provided answer, for it ignores the subtle difference between "move to" and "move in to".

You can translate "move to" as "переехать":

"Семья переехала в соседний микрорайон."

At the same time, "move in to" should sooner be translated as "вселяться":

"Мы давеча вселились в новый дом."

Comment: In English "move into a house" _typically_ means that the house would be wholly occupied by the new family. In Russian, "вселиться" _typically_ means that occupation would be shared.

Comment: @Alexander This is plainly wrong: "вселиться" in no way implies sharing. No correlation. (You may have confused it with "пoдселиться" -- that indeed signifies sharing.)

Comment: "Пoдселиться" indeed 100% implies sharing. "Вселиться" is more nuanced, but still implies sharing. "Я вселяюсь в новый дом" implies that it's a multi-tenant building while "Я заселяюсь в новый дом" is free from such implication.

Comment: @Alexander No. You can use "вселиться" when someone is moving into a new log cabin, with no sharing. I can safely say that, at least, in St.Petersburg  "вселиться" is free of this connotation. E.g., you can say: "Когда дед помер, Фёдор вселился в его избу."

Comment: Ok, this is my own experience then. In your latest example, I would have expected "Когда дед помер, Фёдор заселился в его избу." _unless_ there were others still living there.

Answer (score 1):

"Заселяемся в новый дом" - moving in to the new house. "Переселяемся в другой город" - moving to another city.

Comment: "Заселяемся" - the stress here is on making the new home habitable and cozy rather than the process of moving.